CTS Test:CtsHealthFitnessDeviceTestCases
My device doesn't require  Health Connect Manager Service (e.g. TV) for use cases, but I need to pass the CTS test: CtsHealthFitnessDeviceTestCases. I think compatibility should also consider device usage scenarios and product positioning.
Do I have to support it, or is there any way to exempt this test?
